# How to overcome a spiritual rut and a feeling of emptiness in my heart?

Tags: dua

وَبَرَكاتُهُ‎ اَلسَلامُ عَلَيْكُم وَرَحْمَةُ اَلل
I am a good Muslim, or so I hope. I always prayers on time, read Quran, don't listen to music, and am kind to my family and friends. However, recently I have been feeling nothing in my heart when I am reminded of Allah SWT unlike how I used to before. I feel like I'm looking for the approval of people now more than ever before. And recently I had sinned, yet I felt nothing. I still repented, of course, but I fear where I'm heading if I stay like this. I felt no guilt for the sin I committed and had to force myself to feel any sort of emotion. I really need help on this matter.
جَزَاكَ ٱللَّٰهُ خَيْرًا

Answer (score 1):

Wa`alaykum ussalam warahmatullahi wabarakatuh

May Allah SWT accept your sincerity in wanting to be closer to Him. Being stationary in one's spirituality is a difficult place to be, but it's a good sign that you want to remedy it. He SWT wants you to turn to Him.

See what you can change up. If you're praying on time, can you learn something more about the prayer to be more mindful during it? Can you memorize some more Qur'an to recite in your prayers? Can you add sunna prayers? Can you wake up before Fajr and tell Him exactly what you wrote above while you are in sajda? He alone is the one that can change hearts - and if He doesn't will it, neither you nor anyone can make it happen.

When you're reading Qur'an are you also reflecting on it? Are you listening to how people have understood those ayat? There is so much content available now in English even that we can benefit from. Heart-softeners, explanations of the unseen and afterlife, and things like that.

Are you doing your daily morning and evening adhkar and reflecting on them? Are you striving to learn about the Prophet (saws) and do you have long-term goals in improving your character and habits based on his sunna?

If you're feeling too comfortable, it's time to change it up and take it to the next level. We Muslims are always balanced between fear and hope. If you're not really feeling either, then learn and reflect until you bring them back into your life.

May Allah SWT soften our hearts and allow us to meet Him in a state where He is pleased with us.